# Why cannot I add a DataArray to an existing Dataset with a MultiIndex?

Tags: python, multi-index, python-xarray

I've a `xarray.Dataset` called `market` with several variables and coordinates, one of them, `timeslice`, a `MultiIndex`. This is what it looks like:

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:       (region: 1, commodity: 6, timeslice: 6, year: 8)
Coordinates:
  * region        (region) object 'R1'
  * commodity     (commodity) object 'electricity' 'gas' ... 'CO2f' 'wind'
    units_prices  (commodity) object 'MUS$2010/GWh' ... 'MUS$2010/kt'
  * timeslice     (timeslice) object MultiIndex
  * month         (timeslice) object 'all-year' 'all-year' ... 'all-year'
  * day           (timeslice) object 'all-week' 'all-week' ... 'all-week'
  * hour          (timeslice) object 'night' 'morning' ... 'late-peak' 'evening'
  * year          (year) int64 2020 2025 2030 2035 2040 2045 2050 2055
Data variables:
    prices        (commodity, region, year, timeslice) float64 0.0702 ... 0.0
    exports       (commodity, region, year, timeslice) float64 0.0 0.0 ... 0.0
    imports       (timeslice, commodity, region, year) float64 0.0 0.0 ... 0.0
    static_trade  (timeslice, commodity, region, year) float64 0.0 0.0 ... 0.0
```

Now, I want to add another variable, called `supply`, identical to `exports` but filled with zeros. In a code that was working with `xarray==2022.3.0` and `pandas==1.4.4`, I was simply doing:

```py
market["supply"] = xr.zeros_like(market.exports)
```

And it worked totally fine. With the newest versions of `xarray==2023.5.0` and `pandas==2.0.2` under python 3.10, this fails with:

```
*** DeprecationWarning: Deleting a single level of a MultiIndex is deprecated. Previously, this deleted all levels of a MultiIndex. Please also drop the following variables: {'timeslice'} to avoid an error in the future.
```

I've tried variants like:

```py
market["supply"] = market.exports * 0
market = market.assign(supply = zeros_like(market.exports))
```

both failing with the same message.

I totally fail to see how this process is deleting a level of the MultiIndex - or modifying the indexes in any form. Probably it is because I don't understand the inner workings of `xarray` indexes.

Before going to the `xarray` people and opening a bug report or seeking a clarification about how to do this, I was wandering if the community has any clue of what could be going wrong here.

Many thanks!

#### Edit

In case it helps, the following works totally fine, but it is rather convoluted having to create a brand new Dataset from scratch:

```py
vars = dict(market.data_vars)
vars["supply"] = xr.zeros_like(market.exports)
market = xr.Dataset(vars)
```

Resulting in:

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:       (region: 1, commodity: 6, timeslice: 6, year: 8)
Coordinates:
  * region        (region) object 'R1'
  * commodity     (commodity) object 'electricity' 'gas' ... 'CO2f' 'wind'
    units_prices  (commodity) object 'MUS$2010/GWh' ... 'MUS$2010/kt'
  * timeslice     (timeslice) object MultiIndex
  * month         (timeslice) object 'all-year' 'all-year' ... 'all-year'
  * day           (timeslice) object 'all-week' 'all-week' ... 'all-week'
  * hour          (timeslice) object 'night' 'morning' ... 'late-peak' 'evening'
  * year          (year) int64 2020 2025 2030 2035 2040 2045 2050 2055
Data variables:
    prices        (commodity, region, year, timeslice) float64 0.0702 ... 0.0
    exports       (commodity, region, year, timeslice) float64 0.0 0.0 ... 0.0
    imports       (timeslice, commodity, region, year) float64 0.0 0.0 ... 0.0
    static_trade  (timeslice, commodity, region, year) float64 0.0 0.0 ... 0.0
    supply        (commodity, region, year, timeslice) float64 0.0 0.0 ... 0.0
```